# What is the intuition behind the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in the real numbers?

Tags: inequality, intuition

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality states that

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i\right)^2\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2\right).$$

The proof, with the discriminant argument, is easy to understand; however, it does not really (in my opinion) provide any intuitive justification as to why the inequality should be true.

Note that similar questions have been posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182808/intuition-on-proof-of-cauchy-schwarz-inequality) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374083/intuition-for-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality); however, they do not help me because I have not yet studied linear algebra. For the same reason, an ideal answer would use only (high school) algebra and, if necessary, calculus.

Comment: The inequality means that projection of a vector onto another vector (direction) is at most the length of the projected vector.

Comment: For two vectors $\vec v,\vec w$ for which the angle between them is $\theta$, you have $\vec v\cdot\vec w = \|\vec v\|\|\vec w\|\cos\theta$, so $|\vec v\cdot\vec w| = \|\vec v\|\|\vec w\||\cos\theta| \le \|\vec v\|\|\vec w\|$ since $\left|\cos\theta\right|\le 1$.  That's what I think of when I think of the "intuition" involved in Cauchy--Schwarz.  But I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for. $\qquad$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the geometric intuition behind this for $n = 3$. You need not know much linear algebra, but you do need to know about vectors.

Given two vectors $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $y = (y_1,y_2,y_3)$, we define their dot product $x \cdot y$ to be $|x||y|\cos \theta$, where $|x|$ and $|y|$ are the lengths of the vectors $x$ and $y$, and $\theta$ is the angle between them. (In theory, this definition may be slightly circular, since at an advanced level dot products are usually used to *define* angles. But if you accept the idea of an angle as intuitively meaningful, we needn't worry about this technicality.)

The dot product $x \cdot y$ is also given by the formula $x_1y_1 + x_2 y_2 + x_3 y_3$.

Then the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is exactly equivalent to the statement that $|\cos \theta| \leq 1$.

An alternative interpretation without angles in general, but using perpendicularity, is the one given in A.S.'s comment.

If you'd like to see the details of this, have a look either at Chapter 12 of Apostol's *Calculus* or at Chapter 1 of Lang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra*.

**Edit** I can try to give a very imperfect algebraic "interpretation" of the inequality. I'm not convinced this is the best one, so I'll keep thinking about it.

If you look at the inequality
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i\right)\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2\right),$$
note first that the general inequality follows from the special case where all the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s are nonnegative, since $|\sum x_i y_i| \leq \sum |x_i||y_i|$. Next think about how the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s match up. The inequality says that to make a product like the LHS and RHS as large as possible, it's better to match up the numbers $x_i$ and $y_i$ with themselves than with each other. This sort of makes sense, because if you have $x_1 < y_1$, and you go from $x_1 y_1$ (twice) to $x_1^2$ and $y_1^2$, you're better off with the latter. This is because $y_1^2$ is relatively large, and this is usually more than enough to compensate for the smaller $x_1^2$. Obviously, this is not a proof in any way. But it does make the inequality plausible.

Comment: Interestingly, I am reading Apostol's Calculus; he brought up the inequality much earlier than chapter 12.

Comment: Yes, as I recall, it appears in an exercise on proof by induction. Vectors are discussed only later in the book.

Comment: You need to put some restrictions on $\theta$ to ensure uniqueness. I think $\pi > \theta \geq 0$ works.

Comment: @goblin You mean if I use the dot product to define angles, right? Then that works. But here I'm going in the opposite direction: I assume we already know what angles are.

Comment: Yep, sorry. Didn't read it carefully enough!

Comment: @David I can't help but wonder if there's some interesting combinatorics involved. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to do it through combinatorics. I think the last word on what can be achieved by rearranging terms may be given by Lagrange's identity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity

Answer (score 1):

We can check that
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2\right) -
\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i\right)^2 =\ \sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}(a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2 \geqslant 0 .$$

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. As the OP is requesting an explanation based on *intuition*.

Comment: I really like it.  This is the higher dimensional version of $\|a\|^2\|b\|^2 = (a.b)^2 + \|a\times b\|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality follows from Pythagoras' Theorem.  Without loss of generality, we may assume that one of the vectors is non-zero.  Suppose $u$ and $v$ are two vectors with $\|v\| \ne 0$.  Let $w = v/\|v\|$.

Let $a = (u\cdot w) w$, the projection of $u$ onto $w$.  Then the vectors $u$, $a$ and $u-a$ are the three sides of a right triangle whose hypotenuse is $u$.  You can see this either by drawing a picture, or by computing $a\cdot(u-a) = 0$.

From Pythagoras:
$$ \|a\|^2 + \|u-a\|^2 = \|u\|^2 $$
from which it follows
$$ \|a\| \le \|u\| $$
that is
$$ |u \cdot w| \le \|u\| $$
or
$$ |u \cdot v| \le \|u\| \|v\| .$$

Comment: I think you mean "Let $w=v/\Vert v\Vert$".

Comment: @J.G. Fixed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following arguments are taken from the fantastic book "Cauchy-Schwarz Masterclass" written by Michael Steele.

At first, we take a look at a rather similar inequality which we will show to be very close to Cauchy-Schwarz.

For the case of $n=1$, we consider

> $$\tag{elementary} xy \leq \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{y^2}{2}.$$

If we replace - as Steele does on page 19f - $x$ and $y$ with its square roots and multiply by $4$, we arrive at

$$ 4 \sqrt{xy} < 2 \, (x + y), \quad \text{for all nonnegative } x \neq y.$$

The equality holds when $(x-y)^2 = 0$, which is excluded now.

Let us fix $a$ and $b$ as side lenghts of a rectangle such that $A = ab$. Considering all arbitrary side length $x$ and $y$ such that $A = ab = xy$, we might realise that the left hand side is the perimeter of the square with length $s = \sqrt{xy} = \sqrt{ab}$. The right hand side is the perimeter of all other possible rectangles with $x$ and $y$ as side lengths.

The generalisation from $xy$ to $x\cdot y$ is now very close. For $n=3$, we can interprete the statement that among all boxes in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the cube is the one with largest volume given a fixed surface area.

So, the elementary inequality given above is easy to interpret. But how to arrive at Cauchy-Schwarz?

First, Steele on page 5 adds up $n$-times the elementary inequality for $x_i$ and $y_i$ to arrive at

> $$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \, y_i \leq \frac12 \, \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \, + \, \sum_{i=0}^n y_i^2 \right). \tag{additive}$$

If we take a look at normed vectors, namely $\tilde{x_i} = \frac{x_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^n x_i^2}}$ and $\tilde{y_i} = \frac{y_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^n y_i^2}}$, we are able to convert the additive bound into the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality as

> $$\tag{CS} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \, y_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^n x_i^2}\,\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^n y_i^2}}=\sum_{i=1}^n \tilde{x_i} \, \tilde{y_i} \leq \frac12 \, \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \tilde{x_i}^2 \, + \, \sum_{i=0}^n \tilde{y_i}^2 \right) = 1$$

So, as the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is recovered from the elementary inequality for just very special choices of $x_i$ and $y_i$. But now we got a neat intuition at hand and we can imagine why Cauchy-Schwarz will appear pretty often - as it is closely related to the fundamental perimetrical inequality for boxes and cubes.