# Intuition for Dot product summation and cosine/projections

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I am looking for an intuitive explanation of why the dot product written as

$x \cdot y=\sum x_i y_i = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3y_3 + x_4y_4 + ......$

has anything to do with the cosine of the angle between $x$ and $y$. I dont want a formal proof but an explanation of how the angle or projection fits into this summation.  I can't bridge the summation and these concepts.

I am looking for a conceptual bridge between the length of the projection and the above equation. It is baffling me that we can incorporate cosine in such a linear form.

Here is a comment that I did not understand and would like an expansion on:

> the relation to the cosine (law) may be not the best way to see that.
>   I like to think of it in terms of orthonormal basis. Given an
>   orthonormal basis, any vector  is simply $\sum_{i}\left(u \cdot
>  v_{i}\right) \cdot v_{i}$ by a trivial computation which has nothing
>   to do with CW or the law of cosines. This trivially shows that the dot
>   product gives the components of a vector. When teaching these things I
>   like to use the law of cosines to motivate the definition of the
>   standard inner product. Then CS is shown to relate to a law of cosines
>   (kind of) for any inner product.

Source: [Intuition for the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374083/intuition-for-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality) in the comments of the ticked answer

Comment: Ultimately it's the cosine rule from trigonometry.

Comment: In physics and even in mathematics, the dot product is kind of projection of one vector onto the another. So (for 2-D at least) one can easily see why a cosine should come. It is just expressing one vector(the base) in terms of the other vector (the hypotenuse) or vice-versa.

Comment: I am asking how can the projection be seen from the summation term @Rick

Comment: "has anything to do with the cosine of the angle between x and y" I commented seeing this. Nevertheless you will get an answer soon.

Comment: 3Blue1Brown made an excellent video on the dot product in his Essence of Linear Algebra series. It may help you understand the connection